# Enable/disable iOS lock programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm looking for a way to use your location to determine whether you need to unlock your phone or not, eg at home you just slide to open, but as you leave you then need to enter your code.

Comment: No can do without jailbreaking

Comment: Nah, I'd like this to run on stock iOS

Comment: You can't. It would be a huge security flaw if apps could disable a user's passcode freely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you can't, since your app would be run in a Sandbox, so it can't interact with the whole system (Springboard etc).